# Immutability and static variables

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I am designing some immutable classes but I have to have some variables like say `.Count` to have the total count of the instances. But would having a static variable affect multi-threading?

Because methods like Add, Remove, etc have to update the `.Count` value. Maybe I should make it lazy property?

Comment: Does each thread need to access the same List object or can each thread have their own collection?  Basically, what must be shared between threads.

Comment: No I just need them to increment/decrement the Count appropriately.

Comment: Making it a lazy property would have the same issues as a static variable -- you'd probably iterate over the instances which could be appearing and disappearing as you count them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how you can have an Add method on an immutable object, unless you are returning a new instance very time, in which case you could have a readonly Count = oldInstance.Count + 1?

Comment: Thanks yeah I was writing them for example, but yeah it would be new instances everytime. But the count should be static/global, because there might be gaps if I rely on the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just doing a counter, interlocked operations may be an option as well instead of a lock. MSDN has a [nice example of this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) in the context of a reference count.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using functions from the Interlocked class, at least in the example you gave.

Comment: So that means in practice, the parallel operations will be slower, right?

Comment: Slower than a case where the count was an instance (not that it would work), but theoretically.

Answer (score 1):

> But would having a static variable affect multi-threading?

sure! shared state is affected, by defition, by multi-threading.

> Because methods like Add, Remove, etc have to update the .Count value. Maybe I should make it lazy property?

it's better using a class that [does an atomic add](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) (like [AtomicInteger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) in java) in order to avoid locks: [take a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free_and_wait-free_algorithms)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whenever you update a shared variable in a multi-threaded environment you will need to just wrap those updates in a lock.